# ViewPager does not scroll fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

ViewPager does not scroll fragments:

I include ViewPager inside activity.
And create two fragments, but when i scroll view pager (horizintal) only 1rst Framgent selects:

```
      _pageAdapter=new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    _viewPager= (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    _viewPager.setAdapter(_pageAdapter);
    _viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"!Page #"+position);               
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            if(state==0)
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Page Iddle");
            else if(state==1)
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Page Dragging");
            else if(state==2)
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Page Settling");
        }
    });
```

Here code of PageAdapter:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    Fragment fragment=null;
switch (position) {
   case 0: {
    fragment = new FirstFramgent();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("num", 0);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    break;
}
 case 1: {
    fragment = new SecondFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("num", 1);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    break;
}
}
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 1;
}
}
```

Tell me, how to make ViewPager scrolls two fragments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this change:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 2;
}
```